# Powershell - Compare two vulnerability scans and output BOTH duplicates and differences into a new csv

Tags: powershell, csv, duplicates, compare

I've got a working script so far to compare 2 csvs and output the duplicates. However, I want to compare old.csv against new.csv and output everything from new.csv with a note in the "Comments" column indicating if it's a duplicate vulnerability or not.

Here are the sample CSVs:

old.csv:

```
First_Seen,Occurences,Scan Date / Last Seen,Vendor_Severity,Vulnerability Signature,Vulnerability_ID,Vulnerability_Description,Remediation,Comments
10/14/19,1,12/9/19,5,This is an old vulnerability #1,fixthis#1,this is bad,developers to implement patch,
10/13/19,4,12/9/19,5,This is also an old vuln.,fixthis#2,this will melt your computer,False-positive,False-Positive
10/13/19,4,12/9/19,5,This vulnerability was fixed later,fixthis#3,don't even…,Exception filed,Exception filed
```

new.csv

```
First_Seen,Occurences,Scan Date / Last Seen,Vendor_Severity,Vulnerability Signature,Vulnerability_ID,Vulnerability_Description,Remediation,Comments
10/14/20,1,12/9/19,5,This is an old vulnerability #1,fixthis#1,this is bad,,
10/13/19,4,12/9/19,5,This is also an old vuln.,fixthis#2,this will melt your computer,,
10/13/19,4,12/9/19,5,This is a new vulnerability!,never seen before vuln,wow!,,
```

If the formatting is hard to look at, here's what the new.csv looks like in excel:

[new.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1esI5.png)

Expected:

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd2Ie.png)

The "Remediation" and "Comments" column are filled in manually in the old.csv. I want the script to carry over both these fields from the old.csv to the new.csv for any duplicates.

Q: How do I determine duplicates?

A: My script matches the "First_Seen" (Column A) AND "Vulnerability Signature" (column E) from both csv. If any row that has duplicate objects in both these fields, then that is considered a duplicate vulnerability.

Any new vulnerabilities in the new.csv that was not present in old.csv I want it to indicate in the Comments field "This is a new vuln". This is a simplified example, I deleted a lot of the unnecessary columns and each file usually contains hundreds of rows.

Here is my script so far:

```
$oldfile = import-csv -Path "/Users/Larbear/Documents/Test/old.csv" 
$newfile = import-csv -Path "/Users/Larbear/Documents/Test/new.csv"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $oldfile -DifferenceObject $newfile -Property 'Vulnerability Signature',First_Seen -PassThru -includeequal | Where SideIndicator -EQ "==" | Select * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator |
Export-Csv -Path .\comparison.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What this only does:

1. Output duplicates from both files
2. Carry over the "Comments" and "Remediation" objects from the old.csv

What I still need:

1. Output all rows from new.csv
2. Carry over the "Comments" and "Remediation" objects from the old.csv for any duplicates
3. For any rows that are not found in old.csv/unique to new.csv, indicate in the "Comment" field: 'This is a new vuln"

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the `$oldfile` data into a hashtable, which has keys with "First_Seen" and "Vulnerability Signature" combined.
Then, update each line of `$newFile` with the corresponding `$oldfile` data.

```
$h = $oldfile | Group-Object First_Seen,"Vulnerability Signature" -AsHashTable -AsString

$newfile | foreach {
    $oldData = $h[$_.First_Seen,$_."Vulnerability Signature" -join ", "]
    $_.Remediation = $oldData.Remediation
    $_.Comments = if ($oldData) { $oldData.Comments } else { "This is a new vuln" }
}

$newfile | Export-Csv .\comparison.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Assuming there is a "Severity" column, the value of which is either "High", "Midium" or "Low", the way to add "Due Date" is as follows:

```
$h = $oldfile | Group-Object First_Seen,"Vulnerability Signature" -AsHashTable -AsString
$limit = @{ High = 60; Medium = 90; Low = 180 }

$newfile | foreach {
    $oldData = $h[$_.First_Seen,$_."Vulnerability Signature" -join ", "]
    $_.Remediation = $oldData.Remediation
    $_.Comments = if ($oldData) { $oldData.Comments } else { "This is a new vuln" }
    $_ | Add-Member "Due Date" ([datetime]$_.First_Seen).AddDays($limit[$_.Severity]).ToString("MM/dd/yy")
}

$newfile | Export-Csv .\comparison.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Works perfectly!

Comment: I wanted to also ask @rokumaru if you can point me in the right direction to also have the script create an additional column in the "comparison.csv" called "Due Date" and I want to have it calculate the Due Date based on a field called "Severity":

High = 60 days from First_Seen date
Medium = 90 days from First_Seen date
Low = 180 days from First_Seen date

Right now I'm accomplishing this through excel formulas after I generate the comparison.csv. I was wondering if there's a way I can pipe this into the script you gave me. Thanks!

Comment: Added how to add "Due Date" column. Use "Add-Member" to add a property.